# how to define an async function in readline

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, mongoose

I wrote an async function in nodejs that return value of a query in my database. I tested this query and it worked. but my problem is in the define of readline. when i run this code I get an error that :

```
const a = await Movie.find({}).sort('-year').where('year').gt(X).lt(Y).sort('rank')
                  ^^^^^

SyntaxError: await is only valid in async function
```

how should I define readline function as async function? 
this is my function :

```
async function returnMoviesBetweenXandY(){

const rl = readline.createInterface({
    input: process.stdin,
    output: process.stdout
});

 rl.question('enter the first number : ', (X) => {
    rl.question('enter the second number : ', (Y) => {
        const a = await Movie.find({}).sort('-year').where('year').gt(X).lt(Y).sort('rank')
        const temp =await Promise.map(a, getTitle)
        return temp
        // rl.close();
    });
});
}

returnMoviesBetweenXandY().then(function(result){console.log(result)})
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `async` keyword before `(X) =>` and `(Y) =>` functions as lambda representation. Such as:

```
rl.question('enter the first number : ', async (X) => {
rl.question('enter the second number : ', async (Y) => {
    const a = await Movie.find({}).sort('-year').where('year').gt(X).lt(Y).sort('rank')
    const temp =await Promise.map(a, getTitle)
    return temp
    // rl.close();
});
```

});

Basically, the function should be marked `async` if you are using `await` keyword in the body of the function. In your case, you are using `await` keywords inside the lambda functions. So it should be marked as `async`.

Comment: thank you. I did not get previous error, but I get another thing. when i run this code i get 'enter the first number : undefined'